# Lock Screen Screenshots

Tags: screen-capture, screen-lock

I want to take a screenshot of my Lion lock screen to highlight the new circular user portraits.

Is there an easy way to take a screenshot of the OS X lock screen?

Comment: Did you try the default Cmd+Shift+3? I suspect it works, but I am at work and don't have a mac handy

Comment: The three second delay of Skitch works for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this via the command line if you can ssh into the machine, using the `screencapture` command.

Take a look at [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/103310/screen-capture-in-mac-is-all-black) for some more info.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old but this is a suitable solution for **Lion** through to **Yosemite** and it's pretty obvious.

The commands is:

```
sleep 5 && screencapture -t jpg -S ~/Desktop/screenshot.jpg
```

This will take a `screencapture` in `5 seconds` and save it to `~/Desktop/screenshot.jpg`.

You can quickly jump to the lock screen with `Ctrl+Shift+Power` or for older macbooks `Ctrl+Shift+Eject`.